# It depends on the/a

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Why do you commonly use "the" article with the phrase: It depends on ...?

For example:

> Do you like eating in restaurants? Sometimes. **It depends on the** restaurant.

It would be logically if the answer was "**It depends on a** restaurant" because there are a lot of nice restaurants. But you choose "the" article here. Why?

Comment: It depends on the restaurant I am eating in. Specific subject, definite article.

Comment: Note that an article is not always required. E.g.: "It depends on **my mood**." "It depends on **how I'm feeling**." The object of the preposition follows regular grammar rules and has nothing to do with "depends" (at least not directly).

Comment: "It depends on a restaurant" doesn't make sense because "a restaurant" means "any arbitrary one of many possible restaurants".  But what the original sentence is saying is precisely the opposite: it doesn't depend on *any* restaurant, it depends on a particular one: the one at which I am hypothetically eating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone else did not quite say, the tongue knows reasons that reason does not know. Logic and language are different realms. So I shall not attempt to justify a locution by using the predicate calculus.

I shall try, however, to provide a sensible explanation.

> Do you like eating in restaurants?

is logically equivalent to

> Do you like eating in restaurants generally?

Ask a silly question, and risk an impolite reply.

> No. For example, I loathe eating in restaurants that have boring food, slow service, high prices, and aggressive cockroaches. How about you?

A polite but verbose answer to what is a sensible interpretation of a question literally so broad as to be facially absurd is

> It depends on the restaurant that you have in mind.

The qualifying clause gets dropped, and the sentence gets shortened to

> It depends on the restaurant.

In short, an overly broad question gets interpreted as a more specific question, and the answer responds with implied specificity and thus uses a definite article.

**EDIT**: Notice Michael Harvey’s comment. He interprets a meaninglessly general question differently but still specifically. Language is a social phenomenon that is often used imperfectly. We try to respond to what we believe is intended (unless we are jerks).

Comment: I would say that an 'it depends on the...' answer might imply a very slight rebuke for asking a meaninglessly general question. When I was single, did I like sporty girls? It depended on the girl, and, I guess, the sport. I can't imagine falling for a rabid soccer fan. My wife likes tennis, badminton, and swimming.

Comment: If it is intended as a rebuke, it is, as you say, quite slight, but I suspect that it is frequently intended in a neutral way as responding vaguely to a vague question. The curt “It depends” seems to me to be less neutral.

Comment: Oh, and I have been surprised that no has commented on my misquotation of Pascal. I enjoyed making it up.

Comment: I have had so many disappointments of that kind on here that I just let them go.